How to find position of a Unique_ID in a dataset?
I have a huge dataset with 460 Unique IDs. I would like to subset a specific ID within that column to analyze. I was going serial-wise, but now I am trying to analyze random individuals from my dataset. How do I find the position of a particular unique ID from within the data to be able to use something like below?
plot(data2[[1]]$t_, data2[[1]]$x_)

If I try to use "$" within the data, it is giving me an error because all of my unique IDs are numbers only.
I tried using:
plot(data2$186$t_, data2$186$x_) 

but it didn't let me select the data from within the ID (t_ or x_) and it threw an error if ran as it is:

Error: unexpected numeric constant in "plot(data2$186"

